# How to populate data in polymer?

Tags: binding, polymer

I want to populate the data during edit from jquery
there will be duplicating the tags i have unique id for each tag
below is the my sample code

```
    <finding-pop-up-tr id='uniqueId2'>
    <template> 
    <paper-input label="position" id="position" > </paper-input>
    <paper-input label="expected" id="expected" > </paper-input> 
    </template> 
    </finding-pop-up-tr">

    <finding-pop-up-tr" id='uniqueId2'>
    <template> 
    <paper-input label="position" id="position" > </paper-input>
    <paper-input label="expected" id="expected" > </paper-input> 
    </template> 
    </finding-pop-up-tr>
       <script>
      addEventListener('WebComponentsReady', function() {
            Polymer({
            // define element prototype here
                is: 'finding-pop-up-tr'              
            });
        });
        </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by populating data?

Comment: i have one array like this arrayValue = [ {"expected":419,"position":43}, {"expected":419,"position":43} ].. just i want fill  input box with this data